# how to read two values in one entry in ocaml?

Tags: ocaml

I have to get two integers, separated by a space, in two different variables, in just one input.

I've done `let (c, d) = Scanf.scanf " %d %d" (fun a b -> (a, b))` but I get this error : `This expression has type 'a * 'b but an expression was expected of type 'c -> 'd -> 'e`

How can I do it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works and does not raise any error

```
let (c, d) = Scanf.scanf " %d %d" (fun a b -> (a, b))
```

Since this code reads from `stdin`, you might have written

```
let (c, d) = Scanf.scanf " %d %d" (fun a b -> (a, b))
1 2;;
```

in a toplevel which will result in the error that you are seeing: the parser reads the extract above as

```
Scanf.scanf " %d %d" (fun a b -> (a, b)) 1 2
```

and complains that `Scanf.scanf " %d %d" (fun a b -> (a, b))` is a tuple that cannot be applied to `1` and `2`.

Comment: So basically this code works with a previous input? Still a big noob in OCaml, but thanks for answering!

Comment: This code works if you send it to the toplevel with `;;` before trying to enter the input to be read.